# Basic question about simplifying a square root

Tags: arithmetic, radicals

I just wanted to know how to get from $\sqrt{12}$ to $2\sqrt{3}$

Because my buddy was teaching me math the other day and gave me a list with some basic exercises to do, one of which is to solve $f(x)=\sqrt{x^2 + 2x + 4}$ for $x=2$

The result I found was $\sqrt{12}$ but [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20f%28x%29=sqrt%28x%5E2%2b2x%2b4%29%20for%20x=2) says it is $2\sqrt{3}$ and I don't know how to get there. Is it wrong to just leave it as the first one?

Comment: $\sqrt{12}=\sqrt{4\cdot3}=\sqrt{4}\,\sqrt{3}=2\sqrt{3}$

Comment: And no, it is not wrong.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by egreg in the comments, $\sqrt{12} = \sqrt{4\times 3} = \sqrt{4}\times\sqrt{3} = 2\times\sqrt{3} = 2\sqrt{3}$.

If the number $\sqrt{12}$ comes up, it is not wrong to leave it as $\sqrt{12}$ instead of $2\sqrt{3}$ (they are equal after all). If a question asks you to give the final answer in simplest terms, then you are expected to use $2\sqrt{3}$ instead of $\sqrt{12}$.